# Mocking properties from ProfileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking

So this is getting miserable. I am trying to test some of Microsoft's garbage membership libraries and they are just awful. I managed to put a interface in front of the Membership class and then ran into problems with my class that implements ProfileBase and I managed to create an interface for that so the stupid static create method could be mocked but how can I mock the properties in profileBase which is the only reason you would use that stupid class. Seriously MicroSoft in this day and age can't fix their code so you can write a freaking unit test for it. How pitiful. This is what I have tried so far

```
mockProfileFactoryService = new Mock<IProfileFactoryService>();
mockProfileFactoryService.Setup(x => x.GetUserProfile(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new DummyUserProfile(){FirstName = ""});
```

This is what teh dummy class looks like

```
public class DummyUserProfile: UserProfile
{
    public new String FirstName { get; set; }
    public new String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I thought I could hide the the properties FirstName and LastName that way but the test just blows up and I can see it trying to access the property in the actual UserProfile class.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Seriously - what are other people doing when they inherit from the ProfilBase class?

I also tried extracting and interface using reshaper and that seemed to work but when I mocked it and then tried to say .Return(profileMock.object) it blew up saying it couldn't convert and IUserProfile into a UserProfile? I haven't ever seen that before ARG!!!

I mean - I hate changing my code to make it testable i.e. checking for nulls or stupid crap like that but I would if I could and in this case you can't do anything because what do you do about this?

```
base["FirstName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a good rant I came up with this in my IProfileFacotryService

```
string GetPropertyValue(string userName, string propertyName);
```

Then in the implimentation

```
public string GetPropertyValue(string userName, string propertyName)
{
    return (string)GetUserProfile(userName).GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
}
```

But I am not thrilled with that - I generally dislike creating interfaces that do anything other than call the original code and I don't feel like that is really doing that - I mean it is, but the meaning seems less clear to me? Anyway - I just have the sense there is a better way to do this so while this works I wouldn't mind a better solution if one exists.

Obviously I can now mock this but in my code I have to say

```
taskBoardModel.Name = profileFactoryService.GetPropertyValue(userName, "FirstName");
```

I would rather say

```
 taskBoardModel.Name = profileFactoryService.GetUserProfile(userName).FirstName;
```

Anyway - bah humbug!